# How to remove session which contain table?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

```
$tab=array("hello", "world");
if(!$session->has('session_val')) $session->set('session_val', $tab);
```

How can I remove all values of this session in twig file?
 I have tried this:

```
{{ app.session.remove('session_val') }}
```

And I have an exception: Array to string conversion

Comment: Should not be done inside `twig`, anyway you could "solve" this with the following snippet `{% set tmp = app.session.remove('session_val') %}`, but  I don't recommend this

Comment: Why would you want to remove a session variable in twig? That does not seem the right place, do that in your controller instead.

Comment: You should not have any logic in your twig files, twig purpose is templating, not business logic execution. I am not sure about your use case, but you can use event listeners: http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `flash()` :-

```
{{ app.session.flash('session_val') }}
```

Or:-

```
{% set tmp = app.session.remove('session_val') %}
```

Recomendation:- As other suggested that`twig` is not the right place to do so. it's for representation not for businness logic execution. Do it inside controller.